# How to Concatenate Hex Numbers?

Tags: c, hex, concatenation

I've been trying to concatenate 4 hex numbers and can't seem to do it.

Example:

```
int a = 0x01;
int b = 0x00;
int c = 0x20;
int d = 0xF1;
//Result should be 0x010020F1
```

The results that I am getting using `sprintf()` and bitwise operations always have cut off zeros, giving me answers like 1020F1, which is much different than what I want. Anybody have a better method?

Comment: If you want to use `snprintf()`, then: `snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "0x%.2X%.2X%.2X%.2X", a, b, c, d);` should do the trick unless `buffer` is shorter than 11 bytes long.

Comment: If you want only to print that, use `printf("0x%02x%02x%02x%02x\n", a,b,c,d);`

Comment: @Eddy_Em: being ultra persnickety, use `X` to get the `F1` part of the required result.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, agree, I didn't take note on big F.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Supposing `unsigned int a,b,c,d;`

```
unsigned int result = (a<<24) | (b<<16)| (c<<8) | d;
```

But this is essentially implementation dependent since C++ standard only specifies minimal sizes of integers.

So for `uint32_t a, b, c, d`:

```
uint32_t result = (a<<24) | (b<<16)| (c<<8) | d;
```

Comment: This answer correctly uses `unsigned int`. We should emphasize the **unsigned**. If the identifiers are `int` as in the question, `a<<24` may be undefined.

Comment: In the general case, and for maximum portability (that is, to machines with 16-bit `int`) some casts are necessary: `uint32_t result = ((uint32_t )a<<24) | ((uint32_t )b<<16)| (c<<8) | d;`