# Concatenating hex values in C++

Tags: c++, hex, bit-manipulation

I am having trouble concatenating two hex values in C++;

```
int virtAddr = (machine->mainMemory[ptrPhysicalAddr + 1] << 8) | (machine->mainMemory[ptrPhysicalAddr]);
int physAddr = currentThread->space->GetPhysicalAddress(virtAddr);
```

For `machine->mainMemory[ptrPhysicalAddr + 1]`, this yields `0x5`. For `machine->mainMemory[ptrPhysicalAddr]`, this yields `0x84`. I expect the result `0x584`. However, I am getting `0xffffff84`. I followed this question [Concatenate hex numbers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208555/concatenate-hex-numbers-in-c).

Comment: size_t and ptrdiff_t are the types you want

Comment: What is the type of `mainMemory`?

Comment: @AlanStokes it is a char array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0x84 is `-124`.  It gets widened to `(int)-124` before the bitwise-OR operation (integer promotion).  And `0x00000500 | 0xFFFFFF84` is the result you got.  Use an unsigned type to prevent sign-extension when widening.

```
intptr_t virtAddr = (uint8_t(machine->mainMemory[ptrPhysicalAddr + 1]) << 8)
                   | uint8_t(machine->mainMemory[ptrPhysicalAddr]);
```

Comment: Is that an inspired guess about the type of `machine->mainMemory`?

Comment: @Roddy: Not a guess so much as deduction based on the evidence.